# Обновление данных после выполнения ajax запроса

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

У меня есть ajax запрос, с append'ом в блок div, по выполнению ajax запроса, мне нужно получить данные из контроллера и поместить их в разные блоки которые не относятся к ajax запросу.

```
return (String) view('hotels.ajax', [
            'hotels' => $hotels,
            'count' => $count,
            'cacheLocation' => $cacheLocation,
            'cacheKey' => $cacheKey
        ]);
```

hotels выводится вместе с ajax запросом и вставляется в нужный блок, а вот с остальными данными не получается так как они должны вставляться в статические блоки не задействованные запрсом, посоветуйте пожалуйста как решить данную проблему?
Код скрипта ajax запроса:

```
$("#more").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var destination = $("#destination").val();
    var checkin = $("#checkin").val();
    var checkout = $("#checkout").val();
    var rooms = $("#rooms").val();
    var adults = $("#adults").val();
    var children = $("#children").val();
    var currency = $("#currency").val();
    var _token = $("#_token");
    var cacheKey = $("#cacheKey");
    var cacheLocation = $("#cacheLocation");
    var count = $("#count");
    var data = {
        _token: _token.val(),
        destination: destination,
        checkin: checkin,
        checkout: checkout,
        rooms: rooms,
        adults: adults,
        children: children,
        currency: currency,
        cacheKey: cacheKey.val(),
        cacheLocation: cacheLocation.val(),
        count: count.val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/hotels',
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#hotelsInfo").append(data);
        }

    });
    return false;
});
```

Блок в котором нужно обновить данные:

```
<div id="data">
                <input type="hidden" name="count" id="count" value="{{ $count }}">
                <input type="hidden" id="cacheKey" name="cacheKey" value="{{ $cacheKey }}">
                <input type="hidden" id="cacheLocation" name="cacheLocation" value="{{ $cacheLocation }}">
            </div>
```

Блок, где должна проверятся переменная:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-offset-5">
        @if(($count - 27) != 0)
            <a href="" class="btn-lg btn-primary" id="more">More results</a>
        @else
            <a href="" class="btn-lg btn-primary a-disabled" id="more">More results</a>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Скажите конкретно: что и куда надо вставить — будет проще дать конкретный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

А вставка данных никак с задействованностью в AJAX-запросе не связана, если вы просто на странице хотите отобразить что-то.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/hotels',
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#hotelsInfo").append(data);
        }

    });
```

В `success` у вас лежит функция-обработчик удачного AJAX-запроса.

`$("#hotelsInfo").append(data);`. Добавляет все данные, которые пришли в `#hotelsInfo`.

Допишите далее в этом обработчике всё, что хотите сделать.

<strike>Только я не понимаю зачем вы пришедший объект из `data` пытаетесь в `#hotelsInfo` вставить. У вас получается?</strike>

Comment: Да получается он в String формате приходит. Я и дописываю в обработчике все что я хочу сделать, а именно обновить значения полей на странице но не получается.

Comment: В коде не видно, чтобы вы пытались что-то ещё сделать кроме одной строки. Чтобы найти ошибку в вашем коде, добавьте его в обработчик в вопросе, пожалуйста.